# Finding the resource one level above in path (nested resources) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I am building an app which has a resource setup like the following:

```
User
  Team
    Invite
    Project
      Invite
```

`users` have one `team`. `teams` have many `projects`. `users` can be invited to join at either the `teams` level (and have access to any `projects` owned by the `teams`) or invited at the `project` level (only giving the invitee access to the single project).

I am trying to set up Invites to dynamically find it's parent resource (i.e: `Team` or `Project`). As I understand it, the best way would be to look at the path. Currently the path looks something like:

- `/teams/:id/invites/`
- `/teams/:id/projects/:id/invites`

Is it possible to look one "nesting level" back from the current resource in the path to find the parent resource in a controller action (e.g: `invites#new`)?

Thanks!

### Clarification

I want to be able to use the same `invites` code for both the `teams` and `projects` resources. When the `invites#new` action is called, it checks the path to see what resource has called it. if the path is `/teams/:id/invites/`, it will return `team` and I can then find by `:id`, if the path is `/teams/:id/projects/:id/invites`, it will return `project` and again, I can then find by `:id`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is your invite model polymorphic?

Comment: @leiliu Yes it is. Should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be nesting more than one level deep in the first place.

> **Rule of thumb:** resources should never be nested more than 1 level
>   deep. A collection may need to be scoped by its parent, but a specific
>   member can always be accessed directly by an id, and shouldn’t need
>   scoping (unless the id is not unique, for some reason).
>   - [Jamis Buck](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources)

Your paths should look like:

```
/teams/:team_id/invites
/projects/:project_id/invites
```

This provides all the context needed! Adding more nesting just adds bloat and over-complication and makes a poor API.

To create a reusable controller for a nested polymorphic resource you can use a routing concern:

```
concerns :inviteable do
  resources :invites, shallow: true
end

resources :teams, concerns: :inviteable
resources :projects, concerns: :inviteable
```

You can then set up a controller for invites which checks what parent param is present:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_parent, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  # GET /teams/:team_id/invites/new
  # GET /projects/:team_id/invites/new
  def new
    @invite = @parent.invites.new
  end

  # GET /teams/:team_id/invites
  # GET /projects/:team_id/invites
  def index
    @invites = @parent.invites
  end

  # POST /teams/:team_id/invites
  # POST /projects/:team_id/invites
  def create
    @invite = @parent.invites.new(invite_params)
    # ...
  end

  # ...

  private

  def parent_class
    if params[:team_id]
      Team
    elsif params[:project_id]
      Project
    end
  end

  def parent_param
    params[ parent_class.model_name.singular_route_key + "_id" ]
  end

  def set_parent
    @parent = parent_class.find(parent_param)
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. To clarify, you are saying URLs should never be nested more than one level deep or resources in general? Thanks

Comment: Resources in a REST app. There are valid cases where URLs build hierarchies like for example a news site but thats a whole different ball game.

Comment: I added an example of how you can build a common controller for simple polymorphic resources - if the use case is more complex use modules (`Teams::InvitesController` and `Projects::InvitesController`) and inheritance instead of making a huge tangle of `if...elsif` statements.

Answer (score 0):

When the route is:

```
/teams/:team_id/invites/new //note that it should be team_id, not :id,
```

or

```
/teams/:team_id/projects/:project_id/invites/new
```

you could always to check the nesting by these params. If

params[:project_id].present?

then you are under /teams/:team_id/projects/:project_id/invites route, the invitable_type should be Project. Otherwise, it should be /teams/:team_id/invites/, and the invitable_type should be Team.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I understand it, I need to set the `invitable` (i.e: `invitable_type` & `invitable_id`) in the controller action. Is there a way I can access this information from the path so that I can set `invitable` in the `invites#new` action? Thanks